# coffeescript jquery method returning empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have the following coffescript:

```
myElement = do (-> $('.manyElements').eq(window.elemIndex))

setElement = ->
 [...]
 myElement.addClass "class"
 window.elemIndex ++
```

However I am getting very strange results. When I debug into `setElements()` and call the `myElement` function it returns an empty `[]`. However when I copy paste the `myElement` definition into console, I get a jquery object returned. Why am I getting `[]` when I set this definition to a variable?

Comment: Why are you using coffeescript here? Especially when the simple jQuery statement will do? `$('.manyElements').addClass('class');`

Comment: Well this isn't the full coffeescript file. myElement will be used in other parts of the CS so i figured I extract out that part and have it set to a simpler variable. There are many `$('.manyElements')` which is why I need to specify them each with `window.elemIndex` and iterate over them.

Comment: `var myElements = $('.myElements')` caches all of them to one variable that can be used again and again.

Comment: True, however I'm not merely setting `var myElements = $('.myElements')` I'm setting it to a function call, so caching should be an issue here?

Comment: @user3358302 that is incorrect (you are not caching the function for later), by wrapping it in the `do` it gets executed at definition. see my answer below.

Comment: +1 to keep this from getting closed. The fact that there is an easier way to do it in jQuery is not (in my mind) a reason to down vote, but reasonable to point out in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the compiled javascript, you see that your jQuery selector is getting executed right away because you are wrapping it in a do statement:

```
var myElement;

myElement = (function() {
  return $('.manyElements').eq(window.elemIndex);
})();
```

instead I think you want to just make a function declaration:

```
myElement = -> $('.manyElements').eq(window.elemIndex)
```

and then call it

```
myElement().addClass('class')
```

EDIT:

if you wanted to avoid the empty parenthetic call (to respond to your comment) you could do it a couple different ways:

```
addClassToMyElement = (klass)->   
  $('.manyElements').eq(window.elemIndex).addClass(klass)

addClassToMyElement('class')
```

or

```
decorateElements = ($selector, klass='class')->
  $selector.eq(window.elemIndex).addClass(klass)


decorateElements $('.manyElements')
decorateElements $('.manyElements'), 'foo'
```

just some ideas, using stuff like default assignment in CoffeeScript to make it more flexible.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yep this was the problem! The reason why I put a `do` call was an attempt to not use empty `()` for `myElement().addClass('class')`. But I think that's unavoidable.

Comment: @user3358302 added some ideas in the answer that might give you some food for thought.